# copying html page with mysql data in php

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to copy a file into a folder called profile. I got that working, but I need the page to be `.html`. I also need data from MySQL to put in the `.html` page. How do I go about that?

Comment: What kind of file are you copying? is it an html file?  I assume its not since you say you want it to be html.  Do you know how to interact with mysql from php?  Please add some more info to your question if you want more detailed answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can 'fake it' being a .html file using .htaccess:

AddType application/x-httpd.php .html .htm

Comment: How would you do that using a windows server IIS 6.0

Answer (score 1):

Create a php file which loads the html file and then inserts data from mysql before outputting the results.